# Difference between \autoref and \autoref* (autoref star)

Tags: hyperref, autoref

I know the difference between `\ref` and `\autoref`, yet I don't know the exact meaning of `\autoref*`.

I think that I've read about it some time ago and that it has something to do with the link type in the output file, yet I was not able to verify this guess.

So: What is the difference between `\autoref` and `\autoref*`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to pp. 17f. of the user guide of the `hyperref` package, the "starred" forms of the macros that create cross-reference call-outs -- `\ref*`, `\pageref*`, `\autoref*`, and `\autopageref*` -- are "[f]or instances where you want a reference to use the correct counter, *but not to create a link*" [emphasis added]

Thus, `\autoref` and `\autoref*` both create a cross-reference call-out, but the latter call-out isn't made into a hyperlink.